# Executing SU in a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.10

I'm running a remote bash script (using ssh -t 'bash doscript.sh'). In "doscript.sh" I have a sudo su anotheruser. At that point, the script seems to push a shell and I'm left in that "interactive" script and the rest of my script (doscript.sh) doesn't run unless I type "exit". Is there a workaround that gets around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the contents of my test script "doscript.sh":

```
sudo su diy
cd
pwd
whoami
exit
whoami
```

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` starts a shell unless you instruct it otherwise.

It looks like you actually want to run this script as another user. To do that, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `id -nu` != diy ]; then
    sudo -u diy $0 # Re-run this script as user diy
else
    # Everything you want to do goes here
fi
```

Keep in mind that `/etc/sudoers` must be set up to allow the original user to run this script as the new user.

Comment: Allthough for bash (not bourne shell) it's more convenient to use  `if [[ $(id -un) != diy ]]; then..` form of checking.

Answer (score 0):

`su` as used in you script only runs the `su` line itself as the other user.

Use `su - otheruser -c "cmds to execute"`.